# two questions regarding enumeration in java

Tags: java, enumeration

1. I noticed that I cannot use foreach for enumeration, I am wondering why?
2. Why the following gives me infinite loop:

   ```
   while(keyStore.aliases().hasMoreElements()) {
       System.out.println(keyStore.aliases().nextElement());
   }
   ```

I have to use:

```
Enumeration e = keyStore.aliases();
while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(e.nextElement());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each time you call `keyStore.aliases()`, you get a brand new `Enumeration` that points to the beginning of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, you can use `foreach` with any class that implements `Iterable`. `Enumerations` don't, and they were made obsolete by `Iterators` in 1998.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of entries are small in number, you can use

`Collections.list(Enumeration)` which gives you an `ArrayList` which you can iterate over.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#list(java.util.Enumeration)